# Dynamic column names using DIH (DataImportHandler)

Tags: search, solr, lucene

Is there a way to create dynamic column (as a key/value) names using the values returned
from the query throw DIH (DataImportHandler)?

For example:

```
<entity name="foo" dataSource="my_database" query="select key,value from foo where id=${item.id}">
   <field column="${foo.key}" value="${foo.value}" name="${foo.key}_s"/>
</entity>
```

??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [ScriptTransformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#ScriptTransformer) -

Example -

Data Config - Add custom field -

```
<script><![CDATA[
        function addfield(row){
            var fieldName = row.get('key') + "_s"
            row.put(fieldName, row.get('value'));
            return row;
        }
]]></script>
```

Entity mapping -

```
<entity name="foo" dataSource="my_database" transformer="script:addfield" query="select key,value from foo where id=${item.id}">
    ......
</entity>
```

Comment: 1 thing to watch out for. If you got fields in your schema named `key` or `value` then alias them in the `foo` entity's query and accordingly change the transformer function to use the aliased names. (I unfortunately had a multi-valued field with the same name as `key` and the values from this query got added to my multi-valued field.)