# Solr sort by criteria which depends on query input

Tags: search, solr, full-text-search

Currently working on a project that moving our search functionality from traditional **SQL** like queries to **Solr**. Everything is ok except one!

It's a similar **e-commerce** application that **products have multiple categories**, not single. Also each product has a value which represents their ordering index for each category. For instance, **product-A** is in the first place for **category-X** but third place for **category-Y**.

So that, when you want to list **category-X** or **category-Y**, products should be listed for **their own orders**.

**In short, a bag may be listed in a men category or a leather category. For the man category it should be listed maybe 50th index, but for leather it should be listed maybe 8th index.**

I tried different approaches in order to fetch results which depends on query input. I tried multiple cores but It does not work. In SQL it's easy that to do kind of things, just add sorting table join to main table; but solr side, things are not going well as I expected.

- SQL --> MYSQL
- Language --> Java8
- Solr --> 8.5.X

Comment: What input do you have that you want to use for sorting? Usually dynamic fields (with docValues enabled) works fine for category specific sorting.

Comment: Hello @MatsLindh, How to I use dynamic fields, is it compatible with MYSQL? I searched for details a little bit if you have a best practice example, share with me pls.

Comment: Yes, that doesn't matter. The important thing is that you use the part you want to sorting for your field name, so you have fields like `sort_order_category_y` and `sort_order_category_x` with the values you'd like to order by.

Comment: How can I pass parameter sort_order_category_{my_param}  as like that in data import query? And one note that, would you write your response below, I'd like to mark as approved If it's solved.

Comment: That depends on how you're getting the values now - you can generate the field names in SQL or use something like a script transformer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917317/dynamic-column-names-using-dih-dataimporthandler