# How to separate the values of a multivalued field into dynamic fields

Tags: solr, transformer-model, multivalue, dih

I have 1 multivalued date type field, its definition in the schema.xml is shown below:

```
<field name="fecha_referencia" type="pdates" uninvertible="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

The total of values it can take are three, here is an example where it is already indexed:

```
fecha_referencia:["2015-12-04T00:00:00Z",
          "2014-12-15T00:00:00Z",
          "2014-02-03T00:00:00Z"]
```

**I want to know is if you can divide the values at the time of indexing (I am indexing via DIH) into other dynamic fields or separate fields.**

Example of what you are looking for:

```
fecha_referencia:["2015-12-04T00:00:00Z",
              "2014-12-15T00:00:00Z",
              "2014-02-03T00:00:00Z"],
fecha1:2015-12-04T00:00:00Z,
fecha2:2014-12-15T00:00:00Z,
fecha3:2014-02-03T00:00:00Z
```

Note: I have tried to test regex but have had no luck.
Any contribution would be of great help and well received by your server...

This is my data.config.xml structure:

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource  type="JdbcDataSource" driver="org.postgresql.Driver" url="jdbc:postgresql://10.152.11.47:5433/meta" user="us" password="ntm" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
    <document >
       <entity name="tr_ident" query="SELECT id_ident, titulo,proposito,descripcion,palabra_cve
        FROM ntm_p.tr_ident">
            <field column="id_ident" name="id_ident" />
            <field column="titulo" name="titulo" />
            <field column="proposito" name="proposito" />
        <field column="descripcion" name="descripcion" />
            <field column="palabra_cve" name="palabra_cve" />

            <entity name="tr_fecha_insumo" query="select fecha_creacion,fech_ini_verif,
        fech_fin_verif from ntm_p.tr_fecha_insumo where id_fecha_insumo='${tr_ident.id_ident}'">
                <field name="fecha_creacion" column="fecha_creacion" />
        <field name="fech_ini_verif" column="fech_ini_verif" />
        <field name="fech_fin_verif" column="fech_fin_verif" />
            </entity>

       <entity name="ti_fecha_evento"
              query="select tipo_fecha,fecha_referencia from ntm_p.ti_fecha_evento where id_fecha_evento='${tr_ident.id_ident}'">
            <field column="fecha_referencia" name="fecha_referencia" />
            <entity name="tc_tipo_fecha" query="select des_tipo_fecha,id_tipo_fecha from ntm_p.tc_tipo_fecha where id_tipo_fecha='${ti_fecha_evento.tipo_fecha}'">
                            <field column="des_tipo_fecha" name="des_tipo_fecha" />
                <field column="id_tipo_fecha" name="id_tipo_fecha" />
                    </entity>
           </entity>
      </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Comment: in your DIH query get the vlues in different alias and map them to different solr fields instead of mappring it dynamic fiels

Comment: That would be a good option friend, what happens is that those three dates come from a relationship of 1 to many in postgresql, so I would not know how to arrange it by columns, since if a record has 3 dates, the record would be 3 times in a row, Do you know how it could be done?

Comment: This is my data-config.xml:

<entity name="tr_ident" query="SELECT id_ident, titulo,proposito,descripcion,palabra_cve
  FROM ntm_p.tr_ident">
            <field column="id_ident" name="id_ident" />
            <field column="titulo" name="titulo" />        
       <entity name="ti_fecha_evento"
              query="select tipo_fecha,fecha_referencia from ntm_p.ti_fecha_evento where id_fecha_evento='${tr_ident.id_ident}'">
   <field column="fecha_referencia" name="fecha_referencia" />
           </entity>
      </entity>

Comment: Don't create a new question that loses all the discussion from the previous question, instead - update that question instead - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63472784/preserve-association-or-position-in-multivalued-in-solr